# getHeight returns 0 inside onPreDrawListenter

Tags: android, animation, view

I have a layout that has several cardView, that have recyclerViews in them
in the beginning the first recyclerview is empty, so the card doesn't show.

later on, the recyclerview gets populated, so I want it to have a nice animation to it.
I'm trying to move the other cards down, and then fade in the card.

to do that I set the database of the recyclerView, and then I attach a OnPreDrawListener to the cardview around it, so I can get the height of the view, then I set the view to GONE and run a transationY animation on the card below it.

Thing is that when I call getMeasuredHeight I get 0.
It's almost as the notifyDatasetChanged() only happens in the next frame, so the view didn't get it's new height yet.

here is my code:

```
    private void runSearchAnimation(List<Route> searchResult) {
    if(rvSearchResults.getMeasuredHeight() == 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "height is 0");

        resultsAdapter.setDatabase(searchResult);

        cvSearchResults.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                cvSearchResults.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

                Log.i(TAG, "cvSearchResults.getMeasuredHeight() = " + cvSearchResults.getMeasuredHeight());
                cvSearchResults.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                ObjectAnimator contentAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(cvRecentSearches,
                        "translationY", cvRecentSearches.getTranslationY(), cvSearchResults.getMeasuredHeight());

                contentAnim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "animation started");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "animation ended");

                        cvSearchResults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });

                contentAnim.setDuration(300);
                contentAnim.start();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that RecyclerView supports such animations via `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator`.
See the docs.

Comment: I was trying to animate the cards, and those are not in a recyclerview, but I figured it out anyways

Comment: So please post how you solved it, so others should know.

Comment: Just added, quite the simple solution actually.

Answer (score 0):

so after some thinking I came up with this easy solution:

```
 cvSearchResults.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            if(cvSearchResults.getMeasuredHeight() != 0) {

                cvSearchResults.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
```

Since I will keep getting my onPreDraw method called until I will remove the listener, I remove it only when I know the view has been measured with the recyclerview data I gave it